# Why is apt-get ignoring the target argument?

Tags: debian, apt, version, rolling-release

My Debian system is set to install unstable packages by default

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99defaultrelease 
APT::Default-Release "unstable";
```

However, I would like to pull `automake` from `stable`, ie, version 1.15

```
$ apt-cache policy automake
automake:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.16.1-4
  Version table:
     1:1.16.1-4 990
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main i386 Packages
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main i386 Packages
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main i386 Packages
     1:1.15-6 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main i386 Packages
```

But whenever I tell it to install `automake/stable` or `automake` with `-t stable`, `apt` just ignores that part.

```
$ apt-get install automake -t stable --dry-run
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  autoconf autotools-dev
Suggested packages:
  autoconf-archive gnu-standards autoconf-doc libtool
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autoconf automake autotools-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 125 not upgraded.
Inst autoconf (2.69-11 Debian:testing, Debian:unstable [all])
Inst autotools-dev (20180224.1 Debian:testing, Debian:unstable [all])
Inst automake (1:1.16.1-4 Debian:testing, Debian:unstable [all])
Conf autoconf (2.69-11 Debian:testing, Debian:unstable [all])
Conf autotools-dev (20180224.1 Debian:testing, Debian:unstable [all])
Conf automake (1:1.16.1-4 Debian:testing, Debian:unstable [all])
```

I can specify the package version like this:

```
apt-get install automake=1:1.15-6
```

Which should solve my problem, although the dependencies (autoconf, autotools-dev, etc.) will still be installed from unstable, which is a little concerning.

Anyway why is apt ignoring the given target in this case?

Also - this is not a question - if this behavior is "by design", I think it would be really nice if `apt` could print some informative notice.

### Edit

This is the output of `apt -t stable policy automake` (note: *after* having installed `automake`)

```
$ apt -t stable policy automake
automake:
  Installed: 1:1.16.1-4
  Candidate: 1:1.16.1-4
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.16.1-4 1001
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main i386 Packages
       1001 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
       1001 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main i386 Packages
       1001 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
       1001 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.15-6 990
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
        990 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main i386 Packages
```

Since this might be an issue with priorities, this might also be relevant:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt -t stable policy automake`? (I want to check whether your unstable sources stay at priority 990.)

Comment: @StephenKitt sure, thank you. Done! Note that I have already installed automake by specifying the older version of `autoconf` to avoid a bug in `unstable`. I don't think it would affect the priorities in any way. I didn't know what these numbers meant :) now I know, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you’re seeing comes from the priorities you’ve defined. Setting the default release, using `Default-Release` or `-t`, sets the priority to 990 for corresponding versions; your priority of 1001 for unstable always beats that.

See [`man apt_preferences`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt_preferences.5) for details.

Comment: Thank you. So "Pin-Priority" is redundant?

Comment: Not quite, if you don’t set it to 990. But in your case, if you want to track unstable, `Default-Release` is sufficient, you don’t need an additional `Pin-Priority`. Note that values starting at 1000 mean that downgrades are allowed, which you may not want either.

Comment: In fact your first `policy` section in your question shows that `Pin-Priority` is overridden by `Default-Release` since your unstable priority was 990 before you specified `-t`.

Comment: Thank you. I have removed the Pin-Priority, since I don't fully understand it's purpose. I had followed instructions found online to upgrade my system to unstable. It may have intended to force all packages to upgrade, in which case I'm guessing it's not needed anymore.